# Delete the vertex of maximum degree in a iGraph graph in C

Tags: c, igraph

I'd like to delete one randomly selected vertex of maximum degree in a graph using C's iGraph library. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <igraph/igraph.h>

int main() {

    float dens = .12;
    int nbr_nodes = 100;
    igraph_integer_t mdeg;
    igraph_vector_t degree;
    igraph_t g;

    igraph_rng_seed(igraph_rng_default(), 400);
    igraph_erdos_renyi_game(&g, IGRAPH_ERDOS_RENYI_GNP, nbr_nodes, dens,IGRAPH_UNDIRECTED, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);

    igraph_vector_init(&degree,0);
    igraph_degree(&g, &degree, igraph_vss_all(), IGRAPH_ALL, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);

    igraph_maxdegree(&g, &mdeg, igraph_vss_all(), IGRAPH_ALL, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);

    igraph_delete_vertices(&g, ???);

    return 0;
}
```

I can find the maximum degree with:

```
igraph_maxdegree(&g, &mdeg, igraph_vss_all(), IGRAPH_ALL, IGRAPH_NO_LOOPS);
```

But I'm not sure how to find the ID corresponding to one of the max degree vertices.

In short, I'm not sure what to put instead of ??? in :

```
igraph_delete_vertices(&g, ???);
```

Thanks! Any clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple vertices with the degree equal to the maximum degree, so you have to query all the degrees with `igraph_degree()` (just like you did), find the items in the vector that are equal to the maximum you have obtained earlier from `igraph_maxdegree()`, collect the indices of these items into a vector, and then pass that to `igraph_delete_vertices()`, wrapped into an `igraph_vs_t`. Something like:

```
igraph_vector_t indices;
long int i;
igraph_integer_t vcount = igraph_vcount(&graph);

igraph_vector_init(&indices, 0);
for (i = 0; i < vcount; i++) {
    if (VECTOR(degree)[i] == mdeg) {
        igraph_vector_push_back(&indices, i);
    }
}

igraph_delete_vertices(&g, igraph_vss_vector(&indices));
```

Comment: This is great! I should have been clearer in my question though. I actually need to remove only one of the highest degree vertices, randomly selected (or the first one in the ordered vector of degree)...